# cakephp retrive data from one table excluding the associated tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am struggling with a basic problem. i am using cake php 2.5. i try to apply the find query in the company model and receiving all the data from companies and with its associations, but i only want to receive the data from company table and want to exclude the data from rest of relationships, can anyone help me with this. below are my queries.

```
    $this->loadModel('Company');
    $fields=array('id','name','logo','status');
    $conditions=array('status'=>1);
    $search_companies =    $this->Company->find('first',
    compact(array('conditions'=>$conditions,'fields'=>$fields)));
    print_r($search_companies);die();
    echo json_encode($search_companies);die();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cakephp provide this functionality that we can unblind few/all associations on a any model. the keyword unbindModel is used for this purpose. inside the unblindModel you can define the association type and model(s) name that you want to unblind for that specific association.

$this->CurrentModelName->unbindModel(array('AssociationName' => array('ModelName_Youwwant_unblind')));

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing your data output, I am just going to take a stab at the problem.

Inside your `$search_companies` variable you are getting a multidimensional array probably with the other values of the other tables.

Why not just select the one array:

```
$wantedData = $search_companies['Company']; 
// The key Company (which is the model) should be the data you are wanting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting model's recursive value to -1

```
$this->Company->recursive = -1;
$search_companies =    $this->Company->find('first',
  compact(array('conditions'=>$conditions,'fields'=>$fields)));
```

With this you will not fire the joins queries and therefore you only retrieve model's information.